# Как создать такое представление ? У меня MVC 5, у автора MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Учу по одной книге ASP.NET MVC 
Вот выдержка из этой книги:

**Создание представления**

Чтобы создать представление, щелкните правой кнопкой мыши по методу Index класса
HomeController и выберите Add View. Проверьте опцию, что создается строго типизированное
представление и выберите класс из раскрывающегося списка Product, как показано на рисунке 5-2.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Убедитесь, что отключена опция для использования макета и мастер страницы (use a layout or master
page), как показано на рисунке. Нажмите кнопку Add, чтобы создать представление, которое появится
в папке Views/Home и будет называться Index.cshtml. Файл представления будет открыт для
редактирования, и вы увидите, что это тот же базовый файл представления, который мы создавали в
предыдущей главе, как показано в листинге 5-3.
**Листинг 5-3:** Простое Razor представление

```html
@model Razor.Models.Product
@{
 Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот как я делаю:
Нажимаю правой на метод Index и совсем другое окно. Как сделать так, чтобы было аналогично как в автора ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ткните в `Template` меню, и выберите там что-либо кроме `Empty (without model)`, вам подходящее.

Comment: зы: найдите лучше сразу книгу по `MVC5`, продуктивней учеба будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нажать в Template меню, и выбрать там что-либо кроме Empty (without model)